# Performance Sumproduct vs Application.Worksheetfunction.Sumproduct

Tags: excel, vba

I build an Excel sheet with a `=sumproduct` formula, but I takes almost a minute to finish, so my question is the Application.Worksheetfunction.Sumproduct function faster then the `=sumproduct` formula?

And if it´s faster how do I have to change my formula to get the same result?

Here's my `sumproduct` formula:

```
Worksheets("Übersicht").Cells(temp4 + 2, tmp + tmp2).FormulaLocal = _
   "=SUMMENPRODUKT((MONAT('" & blattname & "'!B2:B" & lastrow & ")=" & monat & _
   ")*(JAHR('" & blattname & "'!B2:B" & lastrow & ")=" & jahr & ")*('" & _ 
   blattname & "'!H2:H" & lastrow & "  = """ & projekt & """)*('" & _
   blattname & "'!I2:I" & lastrow & "  = """ & gewerk & """)*('" & _ 
   blattname & "'!D2:D" & lastrow & "))"
```

Comment: To my understanding of how Excel works, I am pretty sure both are calling the same function in the background - why don't you just try it out? But it may not even be the right approach for optimization in this case, not sure if that is the bottleneck. And posting german excel formulas in an international forum is usually not well received on this site.

Answer (score 3):

Using Worksheet function will not be faster than the equivalent formula. It will be significantly slower if if you pass the arguments as arrays, but only slightly slower if you pass the arguments as ranges.

SUMIFS is significantly faster than SUMPRODUCT but does not directly support embedded functions like MONTH and YEAR (use helper columns instead).
Also with SUMIFS put the most restrictive condition first (SUMIF calculations are done on successive filtered subsets, SUMPRODUCT calculations always work on the entire range/array).

Comment: Use indeed SUMIFS, no need for helper columns in this case, you could combine year and month to two dates (example: "<01-03-2019" and ">28-01-2019" for month 2 in year 2019 on critera range B)++